# Why was the tabernacle dedication in Numbers 7 set up like that?

Tags: hebrew-bible, numbers, moses, torah

The dedication process in Numbers 7 is quite interesting, hence why I'm curious about it.

How come it was set up in such a way that all the tribe leaders had to give those items beginning in Numbers 7:13?

> 13 His offering was one silver platter, the weight of which was one
> hundred and thirty shekels, and one silver bowl of seventy shekels,
> according to the shekel of the sanctuary, both of them full of fine
> flour mixed with oil as a grain offering; 14 one gold pan of ten
> shekels, full of incense; 15 one young bull, one ram, and one male
> lamb in its first year, as a burnt offering; 16 one kid of the goats
> as a sin offering; 17 and for the sacrifice of peace offerings: two
> oxen, five rams, five male goats, and five male lambs in their first
> year. This was the offering of Nahshon the son of Amminadab.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why was the tabernacle dedication in Numbers 7 set up like that?

In short, it gave each tribe the opportunity to show their love and support for Jehovah God's arrangement for worship.  The [Pulpit Commentary](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/pulpit/numbers/7.htm) puts it very succinctly:

> Verse 13. - His offering was. And exactly the same was the offering of each of the rest. This was right and good, because it showed an equal zeal and thankfulness and forwardness to give unto the Lord, and it took away all occasion for jealousy or boasting.

Each tribe gave their contribution as an offering for the tabernacle. The total is described in verse 84:

> This *was* the dedication *offering* for the altar from the leaders of Israel, when it was anointed: twelve silver platters, twelve silver bowls, and twelve gold pans.

We could hardly imagine the tabernacle using only one set of items for **all** the offerings that would be given within a day. These items would probably have to be washed and cleaned prior to their next usage. It would be like a restaurant having one set of cooking implements for all the meals prepared in one day.

Of course, there are some "consumable" items listed for each offering. These would be the beginning of the offerings the nation of Israel would provide in perpetuity.